# How to produce YAML with keys in insertion order Go?

Tags: go, yaml

I'm using [Go-Yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to serialize some maps to YAML. Is there a way to ensure the serialized YAML is writen with the keys in the order they were inserted into the Go Map? Or will it be necessary to reimplement the Marshal interface myself?

Comment: Maps in Go have no defined ordering. In fact, it's explicitly randomised when iterating: http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.

Comment: Try github.com/kylelemons/go-gypsy/yaml instead.

Comment: @hasanyasin That looks like it will have the same problem because its Map is represented as a `map[string]Node` internally.

Comment: This is not a documented feature, just how the implementation worked out, but it looks like if you use a `struct`, output is currently in the order in which the fields are declared. [Here's code](http://play.golang.org/p/q9NgT177g2)--won't work in the (library-free) Playground env., naturally. If you know your fields up-front so you can put them in a `struct`, and you only care about the ordering for aesthetic reasons (i.e., your system won't break if you upgrade go-yaml and the ordering changes), maybe that's enough for now.

Comment: @twotwotwo sorry for not being specific. Instead of Parse, I use ReadFile and then walk on the tree. This is much better than flushing all the document into Go without any control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Go maps do not keep track of order of insertion.  In order to do this you'd have to implement your own mechanism for reading in the keys and storing the order.